# how to know how many object type="file" there are in a jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

i'm created a form to upload images into a blob field of a mysql database.

In a servlet i get the imagine inside a type="file" field in a jsp page.

```
  Part filePart = request.getPart("Name_of_the_FILE_fields");
```

Now i want to allow user to upload more images at the same time, so i put in my jsp page a lot of type="file" field.

I thought that i could do something like this

```
 Part filePart[] =request.getParameterValues("Name_of_the_FILE_fields");
```

but of course this is not the right way to do it.

Comment: Maybe this example can help you.But it is not using jsp http://java-x.blogspot.in/2007/01/handling-oracle-large-objects-with-jdbc.html

Comment: mmm no, my problem is to get a number of type="file". I know how to manage a single file to upload

Comment: What about iterating over all parts `#getParts()`? http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gmhba.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a script that you can use.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

    String savePath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("") + File.separator + "files";       

    File fileSaveDir = new File(savePath);
    if (!fileSaveDir.exists()) {
        fileSaveDir.mkdir();
    }

    for (Part part : request.getParts()) {
        String fileName = findFileName(part);
        part.write(savePath + File.separator + fileName);
    }   
}

private String findFileName(Part part) {
    String[] items = part.getHeader("content-disposition").split(";");
    for (String item : items) {
        if (item.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
            return item.substring(item.indexOf("=") + 2, item.length() - 1);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```